# How to remove duplicated data

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database my_table `[id,first,second,third]` with a lot of entries and want to delete duplicate data of entries `[first,second,third]`.

so that no duplicate for `first` and no duplicate for `second` and no duplicate for `third`
just any duplicate on each then will be deleted.

```
id   first   second   third
1    addy      any     robert
2    addy     kevin    steve
3    jack      ben     adam
```

here i will remove duplicate for  `first` so remove `2  addy   kevin steve`

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Does this mean [1,1,1,2] will be deleted but [1,3,4,5] will not? then 2 will be lost!

Comment: i've added example - yes i don't care if lost just any any duplicate on row first will be deleted even if other are not duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in several steps. I would first get a list of all duplicate entries by running the query:

```
select count(id) "count", first from my_table where count > 1 group by first
```

This should (theoretically... I can't test it) return a list of all "firsts" that have duplicates.

Then I would loop through each "first" in the list and run:

```
delete from my_table where first = "the_first_in _your_loop" and id not in (select min(id) from my_table where first = "the_first_in _your_loop")
```

That should get you started!

Comment: What is *count* in this clause ***"where count > 1 group by first"***?

Comment: count is defined in the select:
    select count(id) "count"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the table name is T, run this query:

`Select T1.id, (select count(T2.id) from T as T2 where (T2.id<T1.id) and (T1.first=T2.first or T1.second=T2.second or T1.third=T2.third)) as u from T as T1`

if the [u] field is greater than 0, it means you have re-occurring data in either [first], [second] or [third].

Next, you'll need to delete these rows, with:

`Delete from T where id in (...)`

Comment: Can you make into one operation? :-)

Comment: Delete from T where id is in (select id from (Select T1.id, (select count(T2.id) from T as T2 where (T2.id<T1.id) and (T1.first=T2.first or T1.second=T2.second or T1.third=T2.third)) as u from T as T1) where u>0)

Comment: What does ***`is in`*** mean?

Comment: didn't test it. but I wouldn't recommend deleting data in this long nested sql-query before making sure that the first query returns what you meant.